# Can't see spring controllers from XHTML file

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2

I am getting "can not resolve variable 'indexController'" error.

My xhtml file;

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <f:facet name="first">
        <meta content='text/html; charset=UTF-8' http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
        <title>Title Goes Here</title>
    </f:facet>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:panel header="Send">
            <p:inputText value="Hi"></p:inputText>
            <p:commandButton value="Send" id="btnDisplay" actionListener="#{indexController}"/>
        </p:panel>

    </h:form>


</h:body>
```

My controller;

```
@Controller("indexController")
@Scope("session")
public class IndexController extends MainController {

private String name;

@Override
public void init() {
    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

@Override
public void destroy() {
    //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
}

public void sayHello(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

My applicationContext.xhtml file;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="tr.source.controllers"/>
 <context:annotation-config/>
</beans>
```

My web.xml file;

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem here is that JSF resolves beans through CDI or ManagedBeans, not Spring-managed beans.

The solution is to configure an EL name resolver for Spring beans:

Put this in your faces-config.xml

```
 <application>
   ...
   <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
 </application>
```

See Spring [SpringBeanFacesELResolver](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/jsf/el/SpringBeanFacesELResolver.html) javadocs for more info.